# Transform a nice pdf into a blurry pdf in c#

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, blur

I have a pdf file and I want to modify or create a similar pdf but blurry, foggy or ugly. It is possible to do this in c#? I have no idea how can do this so any indication will be welcomed:).

Thanks.

Comment: Change the font into an ugly one before transforming.

Comment: The pdf has text and images too and it has to blur both.

Comment: Do you need a PDF File again or do blurry images of the pages from the PDF work for you?

Comment: @Jehof I need a new blurry PDF File.